# pushing down pdf resized with pdfjam

Tags: pdf, pdftk, pdfjam

I'm using pdfjam to resize a PDF to 90% of it's original size by doing `pdfjam --scale 0.9 old.pdf --outfile new.pdf`. The "problem" is that this 90% sized PDF is in the middle of the PDF. Is there a way this 90% sized PDF could be pushed down?

If pdftk or some other CLI based tool could be used to do this that'd be cool, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pdfjam --scale 0.9 --offset '0in -0.5in' old.pdf --outfile new.pdf` does the trick